# How to connect device to Xamarin.Forms project?

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-mac

I am trying to **connect my android device to Visual Studio For Mac using a USB cable** but the device is not showing up on the Xamarin.Forms project.
I have followed the steps mentioned in this link.

[How do I debug on a real android device using Xamarin for Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25192573/how-do-i-debug-on-a-real-android-device-using-xamarin-for-visual-studio)

it worked for 8 projects I guess but now if I try to run old/new projects according to these steps the **android device doesn't show up in the devices list**.

I am still new to stack overflow so I expect that this question is not written properly

Comment: is the current project using an Android API version that is compatible with your device?

Answer (score 0):

First of all,Please make sure your minimun Android version is include or over your Android device version. For example, if you set  minimun Android version is Android 5.0, you device version should be Android 5.0 or above it.

If you have meet this requirement, you can do following steps:

1) Close VS Mac

2) Remove or copy in another place the adb file (in android sdk folder / platform-tools)

3) Launch VS Mac and try to build an Android project. I will fail and if you look at the sdk folder location in VS Mac preferences, you will see that all the paths (SDK, NDK and JDK) are empty.

4) Close VS Mac

5) Restore previous adb file to its folder

6) Now it works. If you look at the Activity Monity, now only one adb process launches when opening an android project.

Comment: 1.Where can I find minimum android version?                           2.On step 3 it shows me that build successful and the sdk folder is not empty. I guess that my problem is related to the Mac cause it doesn't show me that I have entered a device

Comment: You can found this minimum android version=>double click your xxx.Android Project=>select the `Android Application` tab=>You can found this minimum Android version