# Maui app running normal on windows machine but getting errors when i try on a android physical device

Tags: c#, maui

The app was running with no problems.
After updating `visual studio 2022` I had an issue with my app
the errors I get:

```
There was no runtime pack for Microsoft.Android 
available for the specified RuntimeIdentifier 'win-x64'
```

```
There was no runtime pack for Microsoft.Maui.Core 
available for the specified RuntimeIdentifier 'win-x64'
```

```
There was no runtime pack for Microsoft.Maui.Controls 
available for the specified RuntimeIdentifier 'win-x64'
```

```
There was no runtime pack for Microsoft.Essentials 
available for the specified RuntimeIdentifier 'win-x64'
```

The errors appear when I try to run the app on my physical device.

I tried to create a new `Maui` app and run it on physical device to check if the problem is only with this specific app or not and it worked fine(the new app)

Comment: Most probably you have permission issue. Check your app logic regarding required permissions and update Android manifest file accordingly: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/appmodel/permissions?view=net-maui-7.0&tabs=windows

Comment: since i updated visual studio i didn't change nothing in manifest file can you tell me more details about updating android manifest

Comment: The first thing, debug your app on actual device. Connect your device to your computer, and follow these steps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38719305/12576990

When your app fails, monitor `Output` debug window, check what particular error messages are displayed.

I think it is related to permissions, your app does/wants to do something, that requires a special record in Android manifest file: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9GljgwfpiiE

Comment: after watching the video i think it's not a permission problem because I am not tryning to grant any permission also from the  stackoverflow question about debugging I checked usb debugging and it's  working fine my device is detected in visual studio so I think while updating vs something got deleted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied the code in a new project and it worked fine